# Apigee: can't upload binary data for asset

Tags: javascript, apigee

I understand that this is a beta feature, but I am getting nowhere with it. I can create the asset, but when I try to upload the data, I don't get anything useful. This is what I'm doing (javascript):

```
this.uploadImageData = function(asset, imageData) {
var options = {
method : 'POST',
endpoint : 'assets/' + asset.uuid + '/data',
data : imageData // <-- read in from a file using FileReader.readAsBinaryString()
}

console.log('preparing to upload image data');
console.log(options);
var self = this;
this.client.request(options, function(error, response) {
self.uploadingImageData(error, response);
});
}
```

This is the response I get:

```
Error (500)(web_application): undefined apigee.js:2975
Object {error: "web_application", timestamp: 1387435347814, duration: 0, exception: "javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException"} apigee.js:2975
```

I could really use someone's help in figuring out what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

#### Update for 2014 and beyond:

The Usergrid / Apigee BaaS asset mechanism has been drastically simplified as of 2014. You can now upload a binary asset to any entity in a single call. Example:

```
curl -X POST -i -F name='clouds' -F file=@happy_clouds.jpg 'https://api.usergrid.com/your-org/your-app/pictures/'
```

Docs: http://apigee.com/docs/api-baas/content/assets

---

**Legacy asset uploading (here for historical reference):**

I'll provide you the required API POST data to get this done; hopefully you can translate this in order to troubleshoot your javascript with a little effort. Also make sure you're using the latest version of the SDK.

**First, you must create the asset placeholder:**

```
POST "https://api.usergrid.com/{org}/{app}/assets" 

{
    "name": "MyPicture.jpg",
    "owner": "{uuid_of_user_to_own}", 
    "path":"assets/{something_unique-will_throw_error_if_not}", 
    "content-type":"image/jpeg"
}
```

- Ensure you send the appropriate authorization header for this
- Ensure you capture the `uuid` in the response from `entities[0].uuid`

**Next, you need to actually upload the binary data:**

```
POST "https://api.usergrid.com/{org}/{app}/assets/{uuid_from_first_response}/data"
```

Payload: **`[MyPicture.jpg] as binary data/file`**

- Ensure you send the appropriate authorization header for this
- Ensure you set the header `Content-Type` to `application/octet-stream`

The [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) equivalent of this is:

```
curl -X POST \
-i "https://api.usergrid.com/{org}/{app}/assets/{uuid_from_first_response}/data" \
--data-binary "@MyPicture.jpg" \
-H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer {access_token}"
```

If your request was successful (which is largely dependent on whether or not you posted a proper binary data stream!) you should be able to access it via:

```
GET "https://api.usergrid.com/{org}/{app}/assets/{uuid_from_first_response}/data"
```

---

To troubleshoot, either use [curl](/questions/tagged/curl) as indicated above, or use a tool like [POSTMAN](http://getpostman.com) which allows you to set the headers in a GUI, select an image file for upload, and run through the process from end to end.

Good luck!